# android how to remove black frame of a deleted image in the sd card folder after deletion?

Tags: android

I am trying to delete an image file from sdcard.The following code works fine with the emulator but when I'm testing it on my Nexus phone there is a black frame exists in the folder for each deleted image.So, after following posts in relation to similar issue my code looks like below.
I've just started learning android programming and got stuck at this point.I'll really appreciate your help.

`

```
String sdcard_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Expense_image";
  File cacheFile =new File (sdcard_path,imageLocation);
   if(cacheFile.exists()){

                                                boolean deleted=cacheFile.delete();

                                                Log.i("Deletion check","deleted:"+deleted);
                                                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

}

Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<activity
              android:name=".deleteRecord"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.refat.myexpensev1.DELETERECORD" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of API lvl 19 the broadcast with `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` is deprecated and no longer allowed.

You are also missing a permission. 
Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest to read from your phone's external directory.

Comment: I already have that permission added in the manifest file.It deletes the file in emulator without any black frame but not in the real device.Please suggest me what could be the possible solution.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />